# How to detect handwriting vs. hole punch on scanned image?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have the following two functions that I am using to detect if a page from a PDF (converted to PNG/JPG) is blank or not:

**Function One**

```
import pytesseract
import cv2

def is_image_empty(image_path):
    """
    Uses pytesseract to check whether an image contains any characters or not.
    
    Parameters:
    image_path (str): The path to the image to check.
    
    Returns:
    bool: True if the image is empty (contains no characters), False otherwise.
    """
    # Load the image
    img = cv2.imread(image_path)

    # Get the grayscale version of the image
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold_value = 127
    _, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray_img, threshold_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

    # Use pytesseract to extract text from the image
    text = pytesseract.image_to_string(bw_img)

    # Check if the text is empty or not
    if not text.strip():
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

**Function Two**

```
def is_image_blank(image_path):
    """
    Checks whether an image is blank or not.
    
    Parameters:
    img_path (numpy.ndarray): The path to the image to check.
    
    Returns:
    bool: True if the image is blank, False otherwise.
    """

    img = cv2.imread(image_path)
    # Convert the image to grayscale
    gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    threshold_value = 127

    # Convert the grayscale image to black and white using adaptive thresholding
    _, bw_img = cv2.threshold(gray_img, threshold_value, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)
    # Calculate the percentage of white pixels
    total_pixels = bw_img.shape[0] * bw_img.shape[1]
    white_pixels = cv2.countNonZero(bw_img)
    white_percentage = (white_pixels / total_pixels) * 100

    # Check if the image is blank or not
    if white_percentage >= 99.5:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

This code seems to work great, but an issue arises when there is a very small amount of handwriting on the page (I want to keep these images). The code detects it as blank!

I used cv2.dilate() to thicken the handwriting on the pages (to bring it below the threshold of white pixels), but if the pages were hole punched (which are ones I want to delete), it then keeps those images too.

These are the two test images. Does anyone have an idea of how to make this work?

[Hole Punch (want deleted)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OydFx.png)

[Handwriting (want to keep)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C0dnK.jpg)

Comment: Presumably the holes would be near-perfect black-filled circles quite close to the edge, but the written text wouldn't?